# using global array or other better design

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, global-variables

for the consistence of the app,I hava declared some const string in global.h:

```
extern NSString *const GDD_UI_COMFIRM_TITLE;//comfirm button title
extern NSString *const GDD_UI_CANCELL_TITLE;//cancell button title
```

and defined them in global.m:

```
NSString *const GDD_UI_COMFIRM_TITLE = @"ok";
NSString *const GDD_UI_CANCELL_TITLE = @"cancel";
```

Now,I need a global array like:

```
NSArray *GDD_STATUS_CONFIG = @[ @{
                                    @"title":@"a",
                                    @"color":[UIColor redColor]
                                },
                                @{
                                   @"title":@"b",
                                   @"color":[UIColor grayColor]
                                }];
```

I want to access the array the way just like the global const string so that the code could look consistent,but it will be error if I declare and define the array in global.h/.m.
someone suggest to use a class to wrap the array,but it meet my consistent requirement.
btw,I heard someone say it is not a good idea to use global variable,is there any substitute of global variable?

THX.

Comment: Do you try with singleton ?

Comment: yes,but if I access the global array by singleton class,while accessing other global const strings by #import "global.h",the code would be strange.

Comment: Yes. How about using macro?

Comment: not good enough.some advance design patterns may help.

Comment: I think you can use a singleton for global array and global strings.

Comment: yes,but that means I have to modify a bundle of codes..^_^